# Python TypeError: Employee() takes no arguements

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm semi new to Python, I am creating a new employee class for homework and I just have the code pretty much done but I am getting an Error that idk how to fix, **Employee() takes no arguements** even though it has arguments. It is 2 files which I am doing due to instructors orders so here are both codes: 
the functions in my code are indented, i just can't fix that here.

```
class Employee():

def _init_(self, name, id_number, department, job_title):
    self.name = name
    self.id_number = id_number
    self.department = department
    self.job_title = job_title

def get_job_title():
    return self.job_title

def get_id_number():
    return self.id_number

def get_department():
    return self.department

def get_name():
    return self.name

def set_job_title(self, other_title):
    self.job_title = other_title

def set_id_number(self, other_id):
    self.id_number = other_id

def set_department(self, other_department):
    self.department = other_department

def set_name(self, other_name):
    self.name = other_name
```

and here is the other file which is the one giving me the error.

```
from cc_classEmployee10_4 import Employee

def print_employee(employee):

print( "{:15} {:5}\t\t\t{:15} {:20}".format(employee.get_name(),\
employee.get_id_number(), employee.get_department(), employee.get_job_title))

def main():
employees = [Employee("Susan Meyers", 47889, "Accounting", "Vice President")\
, Employee("Mark Jones", 39119, "IT", "Programmer"), Employee("Joy Rogers",\
 81774, "Manufacturing", "Engineer")]

print("Structured Computer Systems Inc.".center(65))
print("-----------------------------------------------------------------\
---------")
print("{:15}{:^05}{:>15}{:^20}".format("Name", "ID Number", "Department",\
 "Job Title"))
print("-----------------------------------------------------------------\
---------")

for employee in employees:
    print_employee(employee)

main()
```

Comment: This is a typo. `_init_` should be `__init__` (two underscores per side).

Comment: As you are new to Python, note that you don't need to write separate getters and setters for each attribute; just access them directly.

Comment: fixed the __init__ but now i'm getting get_name() takes 0 positional arguements but 1 was given

Comment: As @chepner noted, you shouldn't use setters and getters, just access the attributes directly. All of your methods should have `self` as a first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Two things that should be considered with the code that you have posted...

1. The `Employee` class does not need parenthesis after it because you are not going to subclass from that class. `class Employee:` will suffice. I know this is different than how a function would be defined, however this is the way a class is defined in Python.
2. The `init` special method is an example of what is known colloquially as a dunder method which is a short way of saying double underscore method. This means that it should have a double underscore on both sides of the `init`, so it should appear as `__init__`. It looks like you only have a single underscore on each side.